# How can I reuse other external styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to load an external styled component and use extending styles, but it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

common/Button.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
`;

const Button = ({ children, onClick }) => {
  return <StyledButton onClick={onClick}>{children}</StyledButton>;
};

export default Button;
```

pages/Login.js

```
import Button from '../Components/common/Button';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  // not working
  color: red; 
`;

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledButton>Submit</StyledButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0HRa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Component can be styled only if it passes `className` property to it's child. So  you should make your `Button` component like this:

```
const Button = ({ children, onClick, className }) => {
    return <StyledButton onClick={onClick} className={className}>{children}</StyledButton>;
};
```

Comment: What is ``className`` equals to ? Do you mean to pass ``StyledButton`` as ``className`` ?